# Handling optional entries

Tags: jq

I'd like to transform the `priceDimension` parts in the following JSON

```
{
  "priceDimensions": {
    "222FSQ7X57S9DN65.NQ3QZPMQV9.2TG2D8R56U": {
      "unit": "Quantity",
      "description": "Upfront Fee",
      "USD": "493999"
    },
    "222FSQ7X57S9DN65.NQ3QZPMQV9.6YS6EN2CT7": {
      "unit": "Hrs",
      "description": "...",
      "USD": "0.0000000000"
    }
  },
  "foo": "bar",
  "bla": "blub"
}
```

into something like this:

```
{
  "priceDimensions": {
    "ufrontFee": "493999",
    "hourFee": "0.0000000000"
  },
  "foo": "bar",
  "bla": "blub"
}
```

The following script works if **both** `priceDimension` entries are present:

```
.priceDimensions |=
{
    ufrontFee: .[] | select(.unit == "Quantity").USD,
    hourFee:   .[] | select(.unit == "Hrs").USD
}
```

But both entries are in fact optional.

If one is missing then I assumed that only the corresponding key/value has a `null` value (e.g. `"upFrontFee": null`). But in fact the *complete* result is `null`. Why is that and - of course - how to avoid that efficiently?

Ultimately the key/value for a missing `priceDimension` should be omitted alltogetger as shown below. How to do that?

```
{
  "priceDimensions": {
    "hourFee": "0.0000000000"
  },
  "foo": "bar",
  "bla": "blub"
}
```

**Edit** I have noted that jq-1.5 behaves differently than jq-1.6: After replacing `Quantity` with `QuantityX` in the example input jq-1.5 outputs:

```
null
```

but jq-1.6 (see https://jqplay.org/s/XVgl5UCDLM) outputs

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "bla": "blub"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
.priceDimensions |= {
     ufrontFee: .[] | select(.unit == "Quantity").USD,
     hourFee:   .[] | select(.unit == "Hrs").USD
} | delpaths([path(..?) as $p | select(getpath($p) == null) | $p])
```

Comment: This solves only the second part: IF the `{...}` part would generate something like `{ upfrontFee: null, hourFee: 0.0000 }` only THEN  the `upfrontFee: null`  would be removed. But instead the complete `priceDimensions` section is missing even if only one value is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it short and sweet:

```
.priceDimensions |=
  ( (first(.[] | select(.description == "Upfront Fee").USD) // null) as $uff
    | (first(.[] | select(.unit == "Hrs").USD) // null) as $hf
    | if $uff then {ufrontFee: $uff} else null end
      + if $hf then {hourFee: $hf} else null end)
```

You might want to tweak this to meet your expectations if neither key is present.

This has been tested with jq 1.5 and jq 1.6.  For earlier versions of jq, you would have to drop the calls to `first`, which are there only for robustness anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution:

```
.priceDimensions |=
  ({ ufrontFee: .[] | select(.unit == "Quantity").USD } // null)
  +
  ({ hourFee:   .[] | select(.unit == "Hrs").USD } // null)
```

Using a custom function I can write it a little bit shorter:

```
def optional_cost($k; $cmp):
    { ($k): .[] | select(.unit == $cmp).USD } // null;
    
.priceDimensions |=
    optional_cost("ufrontFee"; "Quantity")
    + optional_cost("hourFee"; "Hrs")
```